# Is there a way to get something like the Command type in no_std?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I was searching and even looking at the [core](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/index.html) documentation and I didn't see something like the process module or similar, is there a way to achieve this? or it is impossible without the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Command` is for starting operating system processes, everything that requires OS support is in `std` so no, `Command` makes only sense in `std` and thus is unavailable in `core`.

Comment: So it's impossible to create some sub process with no_std?

Comment: Typically in `no_std` there isn't even a concept of process let alone sub-process